# How to Add State Properties dynamically via Mutations

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I want to add Properties into `store.state` via mutations. Very Simple Example:

```
// state.js
export default () => ({
    Prop1: '1',
    Prop2: '2'
})
```

```
//mutations.js
export default {
    makeProp (state, anotherProp) {
        return state.anotherProp = anotherProp;
    }
}
```

```
// State Client
export default () => ({
    Prop1: '1',
    Prop2: '2',
    anotherProp: 'what ever'
})
```

It all works well. But the nasty thing is, it seems not to be reactive in Vue-Component anymore. If `anotherProp` gets a new value, the component doesnt render it.

If i have defined `anotherProp` fixed in State, it is reactive. I can imagine why. I guees the reactivity of Vue needs to know its data, so it knows on which changes to listen to.

But what can I do? I really need to add states via mutation. The background is:

We have a Databasemanagement implemented. So if a user creates a new database, the vuex store needs to know these dynamically. So for now, we have a mutation, which creates states for each database.

Can I have any way around that? I still have no idea :D

Comment: I don't know about VueX specifically, but perhaps [Vue.set() from this docs page on reactivity](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) could help you here.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Well, have found one interessting phrase here:
"Vue cannot detect property addition or deletion"

I guess its my case :D

Comment: It can't do it on its own, but using `Vue.set(object, 'property', 'value')` will make it reactive.

Comment: A ight - I give it a try. Im not sure how actually, but I´ll find it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the mutation to create the State Property and I try to integrate making this Prop reactive for Vue

UPDATE --------------------------------------------

```
// mutation.js
import Vue from 'vue'

export default {
    stateUpdate (state, target) {
      Vue.set(state, target.t, target.data);
    },
}
```

This is what I needed, because I needed it `mutate` and `set` in Vuex Store itself, not via component.

Thx for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

As said by Lewis and According to [vuex mutations rules](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#mutations-follow-vue-s-reactivity-rules) seems all upfront fiends should exists when the store initializes.

A simple solution could be to initialize an upfront property which contains all properties you want. For example:

```
export default () => ({
  data: {
    Prop1: '1',
    Prop2: '2'
  }
})
```

Doing this you could use:

```
Vue.set(data, 'anotherProp', 'what ever')
```

or

```
state.data = { ...state.data, 'anotherProp': 'what ever' }
```

Comment: thx! :D But I need to `set` these Props in Vuex Store itself. See my Solution below

Comment: This solution doesn't involve to use Vue components, it can be used in the store, as you did in your solution.

Comment: In your soolution the 'return state..' statement is redundant, so it's making the same as the previous line but in a non reactive way. You can remove this line